# rsync does not include some files

Tags: command-line, rsync

In order not to carry all the hidden home folders in the backup, **I excluded '.*' in the exclusion file**.

But now there are some files, **which are inside some subdirectories of the hidden directories, therefore excluded.**

Well, I can't include these files.

```
rsync --archive --verbose --human-readable --delete --exclude-from='rsync-exclude-files-and-folders' --include-from='rsync-include-files-and-folders' /home/andrea/ /media/andrea/maxtor-Est1000/
```

rsync-exclude-files-and-folders

```
.*
node_modules
snap
software
VirtualBox VMs
condivisa-windows-vm
*node_modules*
Scaricati
Scrivania
/package-lock.json
/package.json
```

rsync-include-files-and-folders

```
/home/andrea/.var/app/org.mozilla.firefox/cache/mozilla/firefox/oslnwe1t.default-release
/home/andrea/.config/libreoffice/4/user
```

I've read the man pages, but I haven't found an explanation for including excluded files and folders in the exclude file.

There is a solution?

Kubuntu 23.04

Comment: Please clarify: "which are inside some subdirectories of the hidden directories, therefore excluded.". Perhaps specifically tell which files you expected to be included are not.

Comment: @vanadium isn't that what the two files given in the OP tell us?

Comment: @terdon what I see are contents of files listing what to include and what to exclude, but apparently there are some files that, unexpectedly, are excluded as well. As far as I can see, examples of such files are not mentionned in the question.

Comment: It's the specific, two filenames listed in the include file, @vanadium. Those are not being copied because the exclude file has `.*`, so the config and var hidden sirs are skipped and those files are never seen by rsync.

Comment: @tedon, Thanks, I see!